# Matplotlib treats strings in a weird fashion

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, floating-point

I was trying to visualise the spatial distribution of my `latlon.txt` [file](https://gofile.io/d/o9S9Sf), when I mistakenly forgot to convert the values to float. I still got a plot instead of an error message. Has anyone else encountered this before? Am I missing something trivial?
My `latlon.txt` file contains the following text:

```
1.39679,103.85131,1.39666,103.85068
1.40014,103.77385,1.39646,103.77399
1.34853,103.79679,1.34799,103.79758
1.27054,103.85947,1.27239,103.86257
1.41925,103.80028,1.41894,103.80067
1.41962,103.79977,1.41981,103.79951
1.32799,103.97392,1.33526,103.97888
1.32914,103.9747,1.33526,103.97888
1.29498,103.86996,1.29409,103.86537
1.29498,103.86996,1.29409,103.86537
1.29484,103.86924,1.29409,103.86537
1.29498,103.86996,1.29409,103.86537
1.29484,103.86924,1.29409,103.86537
1.29498,103.86996,1.29409,103.86537
```

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    with open("latlon.txt") as f:
        for row in f:
            o_lat, o_lon, d_lat, d_lon = row.strip().split(",")
            o_lat, o_lon, d_lat, d_lon = [float(x) for x in [o_lat, o_lon, d_lat, d_lon]]
            plt.scatter(o_lon, o_lat, color="green", s=2)
            plt.scatter(d_lon, d_lat, color="green", s=2)
        plt.show()
```

The output for this is, as expected:

[image]

```
        
    with open("latlon.txt") as f:
        for row in f:
            o_lat, o_lon, d_lat, d_lon = row.strip().split(",")
            plt.scatter(o_lon, o_lat, color="green", s=2)
            plt.scatter(d_lon, d_lat, color="green", s=2)
        plt.show()
```

Whereas, the output for the snippet above is:

[image]

Comment: strings = categorical = equally spaced

Comment: wow! now this is obvious! thanks a lot @mozway! When dealing with lat, lon, and seeing that plot, one is tempted to look for errors, maybe one plotted lat, lat OR lon,lon which would produce that plot! There should be a warning for that!

Comment: Consider using [`np.loadtxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for data like this and you might save yourself some bother. Pandas's `pd.read_csv()` is popular too, but overkill if you don't actually need Pandas.